# SQL Query Taking Too Long and Timing Out

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following SQL query that takes about 2 hours to run and often fails with

> ORA-08103: object no longer exists.

The table it queries has under 4 million rows. If I try the same query with only a few records, it works fine (still takes long, but no error). Please let me know how I can change this to run faster and not error out.

```
SELECT /*+ NO_STATEMENT_QUEUING PARALLEL(table64) ORDERED PQ_DISTRIBUTE(table1 BROADCAST, NONE) USE_HASH*/ 
         pt.proj_id,
         pt.wbs_id,
         pt.task_id,
         CASE WHEN rc.pm_budget_resource_code = 'LABOR' THEN COALESCE(rxl.new_org_code, cad.ca_cost_org_code)
              ELSE rc.pm_budget_resource_code
         END AS rsrc_short_name,
         cad.taskrsrc_id,
         SUM(cumulative_amt) expend_amt
FROM     table1 cad
INNER JOIN table2 rc ON (cad.etl_foa_code = rc.etl_foa_code
                                      AND cad.resource_code = rc.resource_code
                                      AND rc.pm_budget_resource_code != 'WKBOTHCOE')
INNER JOIN table3 wi ON (cad.etl_foa_code = wi.etl_foa_code
                                 AND cad.ca_wi_code = wi.wi_code)
INNER JOIN table4 pt ON (COALESCE(wi.task_id, wi.p2_conv_task_id) = pt.task_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                        old_org_code, 
                        new_org_code 
                 FROM   table5) rxl ON (cad.ca_cost_org_code = rxl.old_org_code)
WHERE cad.cost_type != 'UFC'
AND   cad.cumulative_amt != 0
AND   cad.moa_code != 'R1'
AND   cad.resource_code NOT IN ('FLUX','CAPINT')
AND  (cad.cost_type != 'WIP' 
 OR  (cad.cost_type = 'WIP' 
AND  (cad.etl_foa_code, cad.fund_acct_no) NOT IN (SELECT farv.etl_foa_code,
                                                         farv.fund_acct_no
                                                  FROM   table6 vv,
                                                         table7 co,
                                                         table8 farv
                                                  WHERE  farv.fund_type_code = 'E'
                                                  AND    co.far_order_no = farv.far_order_no
                                                  --AND    vv.vendor_id = co.debtor_id
                                                  AND    vv.addr_id = co.debtor_id
                                                  AND    vv.debtor_class_code IN ('OC','ID'))))
GROUP BY pt.proj_id,
         pt.wbs_id,
         pt.task_id,
          CASE WHEN rc.pm_budget_resource_code = 'LABOR' THEN COALESCE(rxl.new_org_code, cad.ca_cost_org_code)
              ELSE rc.pm_budget_resource_code
         END,
         cad.taskrsrc_id
HAVING   SUM(cumulative_amt) != 0;
```

Comment: 1. *"The table it queries has under 4M records"*.  Umm, which one?  Your query uses 8 tables.  2. What have you tried?  There's a bunch of directives up at the top which could constrain the optimizer.  Try removing them.   3. How about analyzing the slow parts with an Explain Plan?  4. If you show a little effort people are more inclined to answer you.

Comment: Nobody can tune your SQL without knowing your tables, their granularities, the cardinalities of your predicates, and a dozen other things that cannot be easily shared in a limited forum like SO. You'll need to examine ASH data directly or use OEM or some similar tool that will show you your execution plan and how much time was spent on each line so you can isolate the problem.  As for your "object no longer exists" error, that's caused by some other process moving a data segment you're using from underneath you. Perhaps a partition exchange, or a move, or truncate, which change the dobj#.

Comment: An explain-plan may help one see what takes most of the time. Better try to see what takes most of the time by omitting some joins and see how that performs. Generally, when I begin writing a complex query, I only write one or two join, then see how that performs, and only of that is satisfactory I add more joins. If not, then I try indexes and/or hints.

Comment: Also note that your hints have no any effect because: 1) `PARALLEL(table64)` - there's no such table alias in the query; 2) `PQ_DISTRIBUTE(table1 BROADCAST, NONE)` there's no `table1` alias in the query; 3) `USE_HASH` should have tablespec

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit tough to know for sure without more details of your database. But here is some general guidance that might help take care of this:

1. **Indexes**: Make sure that columns used in JOIN and WHERE conditions are indexed. This is especially important for large tables.
2. **Subquery**: The subquery in the WHERE clause can be expensive. You might consider materializing it if it doesn't change often.
3. **Hints**: You've used hints like NO_STATEMENT_QUEUING and PARALLEL. Make sure these are actually improving performance by testing with and without them.

Also, you might consider changing the subquery in the WHERE clause by using NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN. This should be more efficient and avoids potential NULL issues.

Comment: Thank you! I do have the indexes in place. For the WHERE subquery, can you tell me more about what you mean about "Materializing" this?

Comment: A subquery that's part of a WHERE clause is often executed multiple times, especially if it's part of a correlated subquery. This can slow down the query execution time, particularly if the subquery operates on a large dataset.

When I mentioned "materializing" the subquery, I was suggesting that if the data returned by the subquery doesn't change often, you could store its results in a temporary table or some other persistent storage. Then, you could join or filter against that stored result set instead of executing the subquery each time the main query runs. Hope that helps.